# cannot find symbol method OnClickListener android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to generate a group of buttons programatically and make them clickable in a fragment. However, I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol method OnClickListener(TagsFragment)
```

That's my code so far:

```
public class TagsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TagsFragment() {
    }

    public static TagsFragment newInstance() {
        TagsFragment fragment = new TagsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tags, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String[] tags = bundle.getStringArray("tags");

        for(String item : tags) {
            //System.out.println(item);
            Button tag = new Button(getActivity());
            tag.setText(item);
            tag.setTag("newtag");
            tag.OnClickListener(this);
            ((LinearLayout) rootView).addView(tag);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("onclick");
    }
}
```

Also, android studio highlights the "tag" on this line:

```
tag.OnClickListener(this);
```

and i have this : "`Expected class or package`"

Comment: `tag.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line :

```
 tag.OnClickListener(this);
```

with :

```
tag.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: don't feel like that, it happens ;). Accept the answer by checking the green check mark