# I'm trying to implement this code on Android, im a noob at this

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I'm trying to make an App for School and I want to make a popup box everytime I press the button.

But then I get the error:

> expected class or package

from this line of code:

```
showPopUp.OnClickListener
```

on line 25

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button showPopUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    showPopUp.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showSimplePopUp();
        }
    });
}

private void showSimplePopUp() {

    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Opening Line");
    helpBuilder.setMessage("You popped my jingles up");
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing but close the dialog
                }
            });

    // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: please post your Logcat..

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22720108/2777098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo but it should be:

```
Button showPopUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
showPopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showSimplePopUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i was following a tutorial and constantly editing stuff that I totally forgot to add "set" between showPopUp and OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private AlertDialog showSimplePopUp() {

    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Opening Line");
    helpBuilder.setMessage("You popped my jingles up");
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing but close the dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
    helpBuilder.show();
    return helpBuilder.create();
}
```

Hope it helps!!!